# Visual studio 2019 intellisense not working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-2019, intellisense

Intellisense doesn't work whenever I open a C# file in Visual Studio 2019 outside any project. I was working on Unity and opened a script file in Visual Studio but the intellisense doesn't seem to be working. Any solutions?

Comment: have you tried restarting visual studio?

Comment: Make sure you have installed the Unity plugin for Visual Studio. Also, make sure Visual Studio is set to be the default Code editor in Unity

Comment: @psj01 Restarting the program has solved that issue for me in the past. I would suggest that too.